# Selenium click on javascript href

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I'm facing an issue writing a Selenium program using Java.

I'm trying to click the following link :

```
<a href="javascript:" id="helkaSubmit" class="ProductsSearch blueButton" title="בצע חיפוש גוש וחלקה לפי כתובת">חפש</a>
```

by using the following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

driver.get("http://mapi.gov.il/Pages/LotAddressLocator.aspx");
((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("AddressInput"));
element.sendKeys("הנגיד 16");
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("helkaSubmit"));
button.click();
String pageSource=driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(pageSource);
```

But it doesn't seems like the button was clicked at all, since the page content which must change after clicking the link, does not change at all.

I need to find a way to check whether the link was clicked at all, or to find why it was not clicked.
Can anyone point me to the solution ?

**EDIT:**

Using `executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('helkaSubmit').href='http://www.google.co.il';");
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('helkaSubmit').click();");`

Worked just fine, so  javascript is enabled and clicking is executed, but for some reason the original code does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("helkaSubmit")).click();
```

Comment: have you tried setting other url in the href attribute of your anchor tag? please try changing it @Itamar

Comment: I've tried it right know , see edit. The execution was successful

Comment: I have also mentioned it the other way. If you found helpful please upvote @Itamar.

Comment: It did not solve the problem , the results were exactly the same as before